# Demonstration of an equivalence between a function a limit.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital, mathematica, mixing-variables

Given f(x)={0 if x is irrational and 1 if x is rational}
How do I prove the following equality is true? :
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing.  I feel completly useless about this exercise

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $x$ is rational then $x=\frac{p}{q}$ when $p\in\mathbb{Z},q\in\mathbb{N}$. When $n\geq q$ we have that $n!$ is divisible by $q$. What is the value of $\cos(n!\pi x)$ then? Try to finish from here.

Now, if $x$ is irrational then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $n!x\notin\mathbb{Z}$. Once again I'll leave you to think why is that true, try to prove by contradiction. And after you do that, what can you say about the value of $\cos(n!\pi x)$?

Comment: So cos (n!pi×) wil that -1 or 1. But if it takes -1 it wont have a limit :/(if x is racional)

Comment: Right, but note that when $n\geq q+2$ (and if $q>2$ then even for smaller values of $n$) we are always going to have that $\frac{n!}{q}$ is an even number, and hence starting from $n=q+2$ we are sure the cosine will always be $1$.

Comment: I cannot see the expressions you wrote,it just appears the code.

Comment: Strange, I do see them. Maybe try to leave the page and then come back. Anyway, I wrote that starting from $n=q+2$ the cosine will always be $1$ because $\frac{n!}{q}$ is even.

Comment: N=q+2,1 and n!/q?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Is it even because the factorial is a product of odd and even numbers?

Comment: Yes. If X is a product of integers such that at least one of them is even then X is even.

Comment: But the product of a natural with any irracional is an irracional right? So there is only left pi and that irracional result. I don't get why it is 0.

Comment: I suppose you talk about the second part, when x is irrational? The important thing in that case is that cosine in absolute value is smaller than 1 for any natural n. Why? Because it is cosine of a number which is not pi times an integer. So for any n we have that the cosine is in absolute value smaller than 1, hence when you take m to infinity you get 0, and when after that you take n to infinity you get a limit of zeros which is also 0.

Comment: Ohh the multiplication of small quantities over great times goes to zero. THANK YOU